# React-native reload app blank screen with this.state.array.map

Tags: react-native

```js
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.itemRef = firebaseApp.database().ref();
    this.state = {
      myArray: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    //get database from firebase
    //................
    this.setState({
      // load database into myArray
      // Example:
      //myArray: myDatabaseFirebase
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ViewPager>
        {this.state.myArray.map(item => {
          return (
            <Text>Something from database </Text>
          )
        })}
      </ViewPager>
    );
  }
}
```

when I run app it show blank screen, I think myArray did not load database so it null and the app show blank screen. How do I solve this problem ?

Comment: Do you setState( your array) in fetch from database  callback or outside?, show more how you fetch and store data.

Comment: http://codepad.org/vjq5YCD8 this is function componentDidMount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to learn JS and understand Sync/Async.
You are updating your array outside of your listener callback. You should setState inside of callback.

Comment: @FrankHN what are you meaning?

Answer (score 1):

On the first render, UI gets loaded and due to the async nature of your firebase data it takes time to get load hence you need to check whether the data is available or not in myArray. Since you have defined myArray as empty initially So we can directly check the length. just add condition

```
return (
  <ViewPager>
    {this.state.myArray.length > 0 && this.state.myArray.map(item => {
      return (
        <Text>Something from database </Text>
      )          
    })}
  </ViewPager>
);
```

Comment: But this is a first screen, so I want to it show content after load database complete

Answer (score 0):

In the render method check if my array is not null and not empty

```
return (
  <ViewPager>
    {(this.state.myArray&&this.state.myArray.length>0)?
this.state.myArray.map(item => {
      return (
        <Text>Something from database </Text>
      )          
    })
:<Text>No data present</Text>
}
  </ViewPager>
);
```

Comment: I know, but I need it show content after load database complete

Comment: after database is loaded update myArrar in state, ui will be auto updated based on state value